# Fatal error: allowed memory size when after using enqueue_script

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, memory

I an trying to enqueue four script files and keep getting this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 103809024 bytes exhausted ... wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php on line 175.`

I used wp_register_script like this:

```
        wp_register_script( 
        'sat-ba-cond', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.ba-cond.min.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-slitsl', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.slitslider.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-moderni', 
        $scriptsrc . 'modernizr.custom.79639.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        false 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-callslit', 
        $scriptsrc . 'call_slitslider.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        false 
    );
```

And wp_enqueue_script like this:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-moderni' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-slitsl' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-ba-cond' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-callslit' );
```

What could be causing this problem? I have registered and enqueued other scripts as well, which I haven't included here because they have been working up until now. Only these four and `wp_enqueue_script` in particular is causing problems. What could be going on?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sat_load_javascript_files' );
function sat_load_javascript_files() {  

    $scriptsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/';

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 
        'jquery', 
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' 
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-bootstrap',
         $scriptsrc . 'bootstrap.min.js',
          array('jquery'), 
          '2.2.1', 
          true
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-masonry', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.masonry.min.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-fitvid',
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.fitvids.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
     ); 

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-callfitvid',
        $scriptsrc . 'call_fitvid.js',
        array('jquery', 'sat-fitvid'),
        '1.0',
        true
     ); 

    wp_register_script(
        'sat-flexslider',
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.flexslider-min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_register_script(
        'sat-callflexslider',
        $scriptsrc . 'call_flexslider.js',
        array('jquery', 'sat-flexslider'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-mobcust', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.mobile.customized.min.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-infinite', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.infinitescroll.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-trigger', 
        $scriptsrc . 'manual-trigger.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-biggtoggle', 
        $scriptsrc . 'call_biotoggle.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        false 
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-mas-inf-blg', 
        $scriptsrc . 'masonry_isotope.js', 
        array('jquery', 'sat-masonry', 'sat-infinite'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-maslin-blg', 
        $scriptsrc . 'infinite_scroll_lin.js', 
        array('jquery', 'sat-infinite'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-mas_hyb', 
        $scriptsrc . 'masonry_hybrid.js', 
        array('jquery', 'sat-masonry', 'sat-infinite'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-ba-cond', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.ba-cond.min.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-slitsl', 
        $scriptsrc . 'jquery.slitslider.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        true 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-moderni', 
        $scriptsrc . 'modernizr.custom.79639.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        false 
    );  

    wp_register_script( 
        'sat-callslit', 
        $scriptsrc . 'call_slitslider.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', 
        false 
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-fitvid' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-flexslider' );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-infinite' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-trigger' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-masonry' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-biggtoggle' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-callflexslider' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-callfitvid' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-moderni' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-slitsl' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-ba-cond' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-callslit' );

    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 

}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire callback and `add_action()` call?

Comment: Ok, edited the post.

Comment: And just for debugging purposes: what happens if you get rid of your de-register/re-register of jQuery?

Comment: the memory error is gone, and the local jquery script is being called, but all my other script are not working/reacting. is registering and de-registering prone to causing memory errors?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't load jQuery like that (please). Use a plugin like [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/) or [WP jQuery Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/) that keep up with the core WP version as well instead of keeping tabs on this yourself.

Comment: Why those other scripts aren't *working* is a separate question, assuming that they're being successfully enqueued/output. Please post your *usage* of those scripts, and update your question accordingly (or post as a new question).

Comment: Not *unrelated*; to the contrary: it is the very *cause* of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennett: the other scripts are being output, but as I said not working. I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: @Zach related to your answer about loading a different version of jquery other than the one in the core: i know it is bad practice, but why is it referenced here in the WP Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_default_WordPress_script_from_a_non-default_location) if it causes problems? I did it as a last resort to get some stuff to work. Anyway, I'll look into getting my scripts to work with the one in the core. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yup, a valid but bad example in the Codex (there's a little warning message above, but the entire example should be replaced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the **de-registering** the core-bundled version of jQuery, and **re-registering** using your own, arbitrary version.

Do not de-register core-bundled versions of scripts (*especially* jQuery) in order to register arbitrary/custom versions of those scripts. Doing so *can and will* cause breakage and unintended consequences.

If you're doing so in order to cause your custom scripts to function properly, then the underlying problem lies with the way you *call* your scripts. Most likely, you are [not accounting for jQuery `no-conflict`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) when you instantiate your scripts.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into the no-conflict issues right now. Thanks for the advice. I'll get back to this thread once I'm done.

Comment: Changing back into the core version of jquery and doing the no-conflict thing solved it. Everything's working. Thanks again